# Is there any json schema validator for Draft 7 in Python

Tags: python-3.x

We are now looking for a json schema validator in Python for json Draft 7, I have found this http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#validator-python website however it only introduced python libraries to json Draft 3, and 4.

I am wondering if there is any json schema validator in python for Draft 7 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, there is. And also very fast. :-) https://blog.horejsek.com/fastjsonschema/